# How to call CSS for home page in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

A drupal 7 based website has a custom home page. Presently, the whole drupal website has one css called

> style.css

. I have written a new css just for home page. Being new to drupal, I have no idea how to specify to home page to use custom css. How to use `<link rel....>` kind of thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do this rather than just using different classes but if you really need to you can add a `template.php` file to your theme. In there use the `hook_preprocess_page` to add a new stylesheet depending on the homepage. Change `YOUR_THEME` to your themes name.

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $homepage_id = YOUR HOMEPAGE NODE ID;   
    if (isset($variables['node'])) {
        if ($variables['node']->nid == $homepage_id){
        drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/homepage.css');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How am i gonna get 'HomePageNodeID'?

Comment: In the function above add echo 'Node id: ' . $variables['node']->nid; and go to your homepage. See what is says after Node id:. That's your node id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the way to go.

If you customised the homepage, you could add a wrapper with a class specific for the homepage.

Then you could target that class with the style.css file and apply specific styles to the homepage.

Sincerely, 
dimitril

Answer (score 0):

Most themes have classes built into the body tag to designate "is front". That said, the proper way to do this is to open up `template.php` in your theme folder and add this code:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];

    if (drupal_is_front_page()) { 

        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME').'/css/homepage.css', 'theme'); 

    } 
}
```

You'll replace YOURTHEME with your themes name.

Comment: your set $node variable but never used? BTW this didn't work for me.. Anything you can suggest

Comment: its set just in case you need it (i pulled it from a theme I was working on). So you can remove it if you like, or comment it out.  First, you placed it in template.php in your theme folder? Did you check to see that it was the only preprocess_node, or if there is an existing function place the if conditional within it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS tag **.front** to target only the homepage in Drupal 7. This works fine for me.

This example will target only the side bar second in the home page:

```
.front .region-sidebar-second{
    background-color: #E9EDF2;
}
```